# Refactoring Javascript for Angular 2

Tags: angular

I've created a simple tool for adding and removing heroes to and from a list using a `select`.

When a hero is selected, it is added to the array `myheroes` and displayed as a list item. The selected hero is also disabled in the `select`.

When a hero is deleted from the list, it is enabled in the `select` so it can be selected again.

This works as expected but I sense there must be a better and more elegant approach using the features of Angular 2. E.g. an attribute directive that listens for changes to `myheroes`.

All advice/guidance is welcome.

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/WTOZRTKkYbBbYv1WLYhB?p=preview)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <p>My heroes:</p>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let myhero of myheroes">
      {{ myhero }}
      <a href="#" (click)="deleteItem(myhero)">x</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <select id="hero" #hero (change)=addItem(hero)>
   <option>Select a hero</option>
   <option *ngFor="let hero of heroes">{{ hero }}</option>
  </select>
`
})
export class AppComponent {
  heroes = ['Windstorm','Bombasto','Magneta','Tornado'];
  myheroes= [];

  deleteItem(item: string) {
    const index = this.myheroes.indexOf(item);
    this.myheroes.splice(index, 1);
    //TODO enable item in select options
    const output = document.getElementById('hero').options;

    for(const i=0;i<output.length;i++) {
      if(output[i].value == item){
        output[i].disabled = false;
      }
    }
  }

  addItem(item: HTMLSelectElement) {
    if(item.value != 'Select a hero') {
      this.myheroes.push(item.value);
      item.options[item.selectedIndex].disabled = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: its working fine what you expect apart from this using angular2?

Comment: It feels like the behaviour of enabling/disabling select options belongs in it's own component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Html options have a disabled attribute that you can bind to `[disabled]="<condition>"`, so this would be the preferred way of handling the enabling/disabling of select options rather that using a document selector.

If you were to change to using this then there would be no question that there is no need to separate out the handling of this functionality.

Also, an added point about your code example - you might want to reset the value inside the select inside your handling for the change event as there is a bug where if you select an item and then immediately remove it from the list, you then can't add that item back into the list without first selecting another one as the change event is only fired when the model bound to the select changes.